# equivalent of RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetNonZeroBytes for SHA1CryptoServiceProvider

Tags: encryption

I am using this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/608860/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-and-Impleme) to encrpyt and decrpyt passwords that are saved to sql database.

Problem is the RNGCryptoServiceProvider is not supported on the platform i'm using therefore I changed it to SHA1CryptoServiceProvider. How do I get round the GetNonZeroBytes?

Comment: Please use a password hash, not a general purpose hash like SHA-256. See [How to securely hash passwords? on security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) is a cryptographically secure [random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generator).  [SHA1CryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1cryptoserviceprovider.aspx) implements the [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) cryptographic hash function.  Those are completely different things; you can't substitute one for the other.

What kind of platform are you on that doesn't have RNGCryptoServiceProvider?

Comment: Perhaps WinRT. It has a different crypto API. Or some stripped down Mono (for android/iOS), no idea what subset of the API those offer.